# Find highest double in a file

Tags: java

Ok, I am pretty new to computer science and I am having a hard time with this. If the following is how to find the lowest double in *data*, how would I find the highest value?

```
double lowestprice = 99999;
int posoflowest = 0;
int numberofitems = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < posoflowest; i++)
{
    if(data[1].getPrice() < lowestprice)
    {
        lowestprice = data[i].getPrice();
        posoflowest = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code cannot **possibly** have worked for you. (If it did, all you would have to do was change `<` to `>`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
double highestprice = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    if(data[i].getPrice() > highestprice)
    {
        highestprice = data[i].getPrice();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty unlikely that the array `data` has a length of `data[1].size()`, isn't it?

Comment: Initialize `highestprice` as `data[0].getPrice()` (after asserting `data.length > 0`) and you will not have to worry about negative values. Then test from item 1 on.

Answer (score 1):

You would want something like:

```
double highestPrice = 0;
int posOfHighest = 0;
int numberOfItems = data.length();


for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
{
    if(data[i].getPrice() > highestPrice )
    {
        highestPrice = data[i].getPrice();
        posOfHighest= i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `if(data[i].getPrice() > lowestprice)`. And `lowestprice` should be initialized to a **small** value. You might also want to rename `lowestprice` to `highestprice` 'cause `lowestprice` is misleading (respectively `posofhighest`). Remember, he wants to find the **highest** value.

Comment: The [1] was incorrect, I agree. However the naming is correct. lowestprice will reflect the lowest price on completion. Sure you could argue that it should start of at 0, but this would be just as bad as starting off at 99999. to be honest it should hold the largest value of a double, presuming that data is an array of doubles.

Comment: Well, the task was to find the **highest** value, not the **smallest** :)

Answer (score 0):

Implying you can get the doubles into an array of doubles

```
double[] array = new double[] { 1.1, 9.15, 7.15, 4.51 };
```

Simply do

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Later,

```
System.out.println("Largest double in array: " + array[array.length - 1]);
```

Output:

```
Largest double in array: 9.15
```

If you can't get them in an array, you should try to, it would be a nice thing to know, considering you're just starting off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is going to work to find the lowest - I don't think your 'for' condition is correct and you have a '1' where you want an 'i'. Hopefully this will correct that:

```
double lowestprice = 99999; // The current lowest value
int posoflowest = 0;        // Where in the collection of values the lowest value is
int numberofitems = 0;      // How many 


// For each double in your collection. This will iterate from the first item in 
// data[] to the last.
for (int i = 0; i < numberofitems ; i++)
{
    // Is the current price lower than the lowest we have found?
    // So the first time around, this will see if the price of the first item in 
    // data[] is lower than 99999. If it is, we update the lowest price and set
    // 'posoflowest'. 
    if(data[i].getPrice() < lowestprice)
    {
        lowestprice = data[i].getPrice();
        posoflowest = i;
    }
}
```

If we take that as hopefully getting your lowest value properly, we can add something very similar for the highest:

```
double lowestPrice = 99999; // The current lowest value
double highestPrice = 0;    // The current highest price
int posOfLowest = 0;        // Where in data[] is the lowest priced item?
int posOfHighest = 0;       // Where in data[] is the highest priced item?
int numberOfItems = 0;      // How many items in data[]?


// For each double in your collection. This will iterate from the first item in 
// data[] to the last.
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems ; i++)
{
    // Is the current price lower than the lowest we have found?
    if(data[i].getPrice() < lowestPrice)
    {
        lowestPrice = data[i].getPrice();
        posOfLowest = i;
    }

    if(data[i].getPrice() > highestPrice)
    {
        highestPrice= data[i].getPrice();
        posOfHighest = i;
    }
}
```

Hope that makes sense.